# ¿Como puedo configurar astro nvim?

Tags: lua, nvim

intento configurar astro nvim pero aun soy nuevo en esto de la configuración de nvim con lua.
encontre este codigo en github.com https://github.com/talk2drys/dotfiles/blob/59cd81a55fb81408a75a1758ee5ff048e6e140c8/private_dot_config/astronvim/lua/user/plugins/astrotheme.lua#L4

```
return {
  "AstroNvim/astrotheme",
  opts = {
    termguicolors = true, -- Bool 
    terminal_color = true, -- Bool 
    highlights = {
      astrodark = {
        modify_hl_groups = function(hl, c) -- modify_hl_groups function allows you to modify hl groups,
          hl.Normal.bg = c.black
        end,
      },
    },
  },
}
```

pero la verdad no se que hace o como lo hace, lo que quiero realizar es quitar el fondo no megusta como se ve me gustaria que fuse transaparente.
[image: Astro nvim terminal flotante]